# MariaDB Procedure run comand create trigger

Tags: mariadb

Is it possible to run command to create table and trigger from a procedure?

1295 - This command is not supported in the prepared statement protocol yet

```
CREATE DEFINER=`username`@`%` PROCEDURE `tg_audit`(IN `table_name` varchar(100))
BEGIN
    DECLARE sqlx LONGTEXT;
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE column_name VARCHAR(100);
    DECLARE cursor_column CURSOR FOR SELECT i.column_name FROM information_schema.columns i WHERE i.table_name = table_name;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;    
    
    -- DELETE TRIGGER
    SET sqlx = CONCAT('DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS ', table_name,'_update_audit_trigger');   
    PREPARE stmt FROM sqlx;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
    
    
    -- CREATE TRIGGER
    SET sqlx = CONCAT('CREATE TRIGGER ',table_name,'_update_audit_trigger AFTER UPDATE ON `',table_name,'` FOR EACH ROW\n',
                                        'BEGIN\n\n' ,
                                        '\tDECLARE m_change text;\n',
                                        '\tSET m_change = JSON_OBJECT();\n\n'
    );
        
    OPEN cursor_column;
        REPEAT
        FETCH cursor_column INTO column_name;
                IF NOT done THEN
                    
                    SET sqlx = CONCAT(sqlx, '\tIF coalesce(NEW.',column_name,', \'\') != coalesce(OLD.',column_name,', \'\') THEN\n',
                                                        '\t\tSET m_change = JSON_SET(m_change, \'$.',column_name,'\', NEW.',column_name,');\n',
                                                        '\tEND IF;\n\n'
                                            );             
                    
                    
                END IF;
        UNTIL done END REPEAT;
    CLOSE cursor_column;
    
    SET sqlx = CONCAT(sqlx, 'END;');
        
    PREPARE stmt FROM sqlx;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

END
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL/MariaDB can create a table within the procedure. And this operation does not need in prepared statement until the structure of the table should be built dynamically.

> ```
> CREATE PROCEDURE test ( param INT )
> BEGIN
> -- create table by statement
>     CREATE TABLE test (id INT, val INT);
> -- create table by dynamic SQL
>     SET @sql := CONCAT('CREATE TABLE test', param, ' (id INT, val INT)');
>     PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
>     EXECUTE stmt;
>     DROP PREPARE stmt;
> END
> ```

> ```
> CALL test(1);
> SHOW TABLES;
> ```
>
> ```
> | Tables_in_db_1102741712 |
> | :---------------------- |
> | test                    |
> | test1                   |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=e4742c80fe002a687534de7de792b4ad)*

MySQL/MariaDB cannot create a trigger within stored procedure and/or within prepared statement. At least in currect version.

Comment: I got it, but apparently it only works on version 10.6 or higher, but for now I can't upload the database version

db<>fiddle [link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=8b83f8a0ac9bdfd45f06b847b24f7c57)

Comment: @ElvisReis True, MariaDB 10.6 may do. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=fefb638b75946759fe0d6f88e92dd13d And your code is executed too. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=c2f0135b80082b73fc647fd5b5a2e856 But your trigger do nothing with the JSON value built in the variable...